# Is all data in Lisp immutable?

Tags: lisp

In [this article](http://fpcomplete.com/the-downfall-of-imperative-programming/), the author praised functional programming with 2 main good features.
But he didn't mention (Common) Lisp.

Does Lisp's data meet this "all data is immutable"?

Comment: That article is the typical "new born" convert to the functional programming religion making the typical clueless renouncement of the evil of imperative programming. "I've been saved". (Well, not I literally, but an object similar to me was constructed, only without the imperative programming bits.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Common Lisp you have the option of using a functional style.  Avoid `setf`, `setq`, and the like, and you've got a functional programming language. In other words, don't change any variable values, don't change the contents of compound data structures (cons, vectors, structures, etc) after creation. Functions take input and produce output without modifying state.

So, while Common Lisp provides operations that are imperative you don't need to use them if you don't want to.

Answer (score 10):

In Common Lisp, all the data (such as primitive variable references, lists, arrays and hash tables) are mutable by default, so that nothing can prevent someone from changing the value of a variable, an element of a sequence or a field of a structure.

However, if we're not talking about primitive data types but about user-defined data, that is about the CLOS structures and classes, their slots can be made read-only. For example, for structures:

```
(defstruct person
  (name nil :type string :read-only t)
  (age nil :type (integer 0 100)))

(let ((john (make-person :name "John" :age 30)))
  (princ john)
  ;; * `age' is mutable:
  (incf (person-age john))
  (princ john)
  ;; * `name' is not:
  ;; (setf (person-name john) "garbage name")
  ;; ^ you can't do this because the `defstruct' macro just don't emit SETFer
  ;;   for the `name' slot as you made it read-only.
  )
```

Classes provide even more access control for the slots (this is similar to the mechanism of the `const` qualifier in C, the difference is that in Common Lisp it is not a compile-time guarantee, but an exceptions which can be handled in a restarts), you can give them read and write, read-only, write-only, or no access.

---

See the following links for more information:

- http://psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter07.html
- http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html

Comment: Note: if you uncomment the call to `person-name' then you get a STYLE-WARNING about undefined function (e.g., in SBCL), so this is a weak form of the compile-time guarantee that prohibits write access to a certain slot.

Comment: Can I even prevent `(setf (slot-value [..]))` from mutating?

Answer (score -1):

No. Data in Common Lisp is not immutable.

as seen in SBCL using the `setf` function

```
* (setf x 0)
0
* x
0
* (setf x 1)
1
* x
1
```

Comment: I think your example does not say x is mutable. Take this example:
  (define x 10)
   x
=> 10
   (define y x)
   y
=> 10
   (define x 20)
   x
=> 20
   y
=> 10
.
X was merely a symbol binding itself to 10 initially. The value 10 did not change. You just bound X to another value.